# C# console game space invader

Tags: c#, console, console-application

**Hey there,** im writting a code with an Space ship but i cant move it to the left or right, and i wanted to ask if maybe somebody could help me because i dont understand it. And i tried some things like to write it in a other way but it dont works, im new to programming probably u can see it by the way i wrote my code.

```
           string player = @"
                         ^
                         o
                       | o |
                     /\\\o///\
                       </o\>";
        char laser = '|';
        int moves = 0;
        int xlaser = rnd.Next(width), ylaser = rnd.Next(hight);
        WriteHere(xlaser, ylaser, laser);
        WriteHere(x, y, player);
        // game loop
        do
        {

            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);

            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        {
                            if (y > 0)
                            {
                                //y -= 1;
                                y--; // ist //y = y - 1;
                            }
                            moves++;
                        }
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        {
                            if (y < hight - 1)
                            {
                                y++; // ist y = y + 1;
                            }
                            moves++;
                        }
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                        {
                            if (x > 0)
                            {
                                x--;
                            }
                            moves++;
                        }
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                        {
                            if (x < width - 1)
                            {
                                x++;
                            }
                            moves++;
                        }
                        break;
                }

                Console.Clear();
                Writehere(x, y, player);
```

Comment: Does up/down movement work? Also you seem to have a typo, you call `WriteHere` in one place and `Writehere` in other place. What is the do while loop condition?

Comment: Yeah Up/down works! but first i wriote the player out of the loop and then i wrote the player on the bottom to have him moving if i would just wrote it on the top i couldnt move him not up/down or left/right

Comment: I made it when i press escape i leave the game the condition is (**while (true);**

Comment: Is that real c# code above? Are you editing/running this in visual studio ? I ask as there are syntax errors in it.

Comment: yea im running it in vs 2017 community but its not the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define your player string without whitespace and write it to the console line by line it works. I'm sure there are better solutions but as a quick resolve this might be ok.

Replace WriteHere with this code

```
static void WriteHere(int x, int y, string s)
{
    foreach (var line in s.Split('\n'))
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.Write(line);
        y++;
    }
}
```

And for the player, instead of

```
            string player = @"
                            ^
                            o
                          | o |
                        /\\\o///\
                          </o\>";
```

Do it like this (note the difference in whitespace on the left).

```
            string player = @"
    ^
    o
  | o |
/\\\o///\
  </o\>";
```

Comment: **Thank you @Marius** for your fast help